# Как из своей программы сделать снимок экрана рабочего стола телефона?

Tags: android, экран

Требуется сделать снимок рабочего стола телефона в своей программе ну и потом редактировать его. Не могу понять как сделать скриншот именно рабочего стола телефона.

Comment: @miha_dev да, мое приложение должно делать скрин

Comment: т.е. вы будете снимать экран своего приложения или все таки рабочий стол? Пользователь будет кнопку в приложении нажимать? или все таки нажимая кнопки телефона, а ваше приложение должно перехватить скриншот и открыть окно редактирования?

Comment: @miha_dev пользователь в моем приложении нажимает кнопку, делается снимок рабочего стола телефона, не UI моего приложения... Как я прочитал, android запрещает такое делать (только если не рутированный тел)